# Why is my truck randomly blowing cold air with heater on?

Tags: ford, heater, f-150

I have a 2016 Ford F150 randomly with my heat on it will blow cold air sometimes when idling and sometimes not OK while I am driving or revving my engine. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked your coolant level?